# Can I attach criterias for a HasMany entity?

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I have an Incident class that uses the HasMany attribute to a Location class. All works using the static Find methods. But I need to add a where clause to the Location table. I can use the Where attribute but I don't always want that clause when fetching results.

Is there any way to maybe use DetachedCriteria or something similar while querying for Incident to filter the Location table? I *could* use hql but it seems that I have to create my joins manually which seems redundant if I use the HasMany attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[HasMany]` attribute has a `Where` property that filters the relationship.

Another way to do semi-global filtering is with [session filters](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-15-filtering-data/1nr4enxv3dpeq/18#).